# Sending a notification to the server when the android app if closed

Tags: php, android, notifications

I have created an application which is used to locate other people and a server... Now if anyone closes an app by Advanced Task Killer (This app is used to kill un-necessary application) how do i send a notification or a message to the server saying this person has closed the app.
example:- I have an app which detects other peoples location. And 2 more friends  of mine have it. There is a server which examines our location. Now if one of my friend closes the app as said above how do i send a message or notification to the server created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before callling finish(); (if ur calling) or in onDestory();
send "closed" as request parameter to your server url like
"http:YOUR_SERVER_URL/?status=closed" using HttpClient post request.

at server catch it as request.getparamer("status");//Its JSP code

if you want inform ur frends about this use C2DM as push notification.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i send a notification or a message to the server saying this person has closed the app

You don't. If the user force-stops your app, you do not get control.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the activity life cycle. I think what you are looking for, is to call the server in the onDestory() in the current activity...